# Python 3 idiomatic import with Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

Flask suggests the following file layout:

```
runflaskapp.py 
flaskapp/ 
    __init__.py
```

runflaskapp.py contains:

```
from flaskapp import app 
app.run(debug=True)
```

flaskapp/**init**.py contains:

```
from flask import Flask 
app = Flask(__name__)
```

Running this with 'python3 runflaskapp.py' works fine. However it 
seems to me that a more Python3onic way of doing this would be to 
rename 'runflaskapp.py' as 'flaskapp/**main**.py' and then run 
the whole thing as 'python3 -m flaskapp'. Unfortunately this doesn't 
work:

```
$ python3 -m flaskapp 
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ 
 * Restarting with reloader 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "/home/username/src/flaskapp/__main__.py", line 1, in <module> 
    from flaskapp import app 
ImportError: No module named 'flaskapp'
```

Does anyone know why and how to fix it?

Comment: Which version of Python 3.x is this?

Comment: I'm using Python 3.4.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`-m`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m) flag does this:

> Search sys.path for the named module and execute its contents as the `__main__` module… When a package name is supplied instead of a normal module, the interpreter will execute `<pkg>.__main__` as the main module.

In other words, `flaskapp` is not imported as `flaskapp`, but as `__main__`, just like a script would be, and then its `__main__` module gets executed.

This means `from flaskapp import app` will not work, because there is nothing named `flaskapp`.

But the relative import `from . import app` will. So, as long as there are no absolute imports anywhere in `flaskapp` except in your new `__main__.py` file, that one-liner should do it.